# Замена домена сайта

Tags: php, wordpress

Столкнулся с задачей, есть 2 одинаковых сайта на `wordpress`, бд одна, различие лишь в том, что у первого сайта есть выход в интернет, а другой развернут локально, у одного домен www.example.ru у другого example.local, как в принципе можно заменять ссылки, если доступа в интернет у локальной версии нет? Пробую так:

```
function checkURL($url){
    $domain = get_bloginfo('url');
    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    /* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
    $response = curl_exec($handle);

    /* Check for 404 (file not found). */
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if($httpCode == 404) {
        $url = str_replace($domain, 'example.local', $url);
        return $url;
        /* Handle 404 here. */
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
    curl_close($handle);
    wp_die();
}
```

И у каждой ссылки на сайте делаю эту проверку, но проблема в том что из-за этого сильно увеличивается время загрузки сайта, как по-другому можно решить?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561/220220

Answer (score 0):

У локального сайта в файл `wp-config.php` добавьте строки:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.local' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.local' );
```

Comment: Такой способ работает только на самых простых сайтах, без сериализованных данных